# How to implement onchildclick listener in this example?

Tags: java, android, listview, clickable

So i am having an expandable listview. What i want is to make clickable each children. if I press the first one I want to open the class1, if I press the second one I want to open the class2, if I press the third one I want to open the class3 and so on... I am new in programming so please explain me like you would do it for a dummie.

This is my Activity

```
public class Mecanica  extends ExpandableListActivity implements OnChildClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ExpandableListView expandbleLis = getExpandableListView();
        expandbleLis.setDividerHeight(2);
        expandbleLis.setGroupIndicator(null);
        expandbleLis.setClickable(true);

        setGroupData();
        setChildGroupData();

        NewAdapter mNewAdapter = new NewAdapter(groupItem, childItem);
        mNewAdapter.setInflater((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE), this);
        getExpandableListView().setAdapter(mNewAdapter);
        expandbleLis.setOnChildClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setGroupData() {
        groupItem.add("Directia");
        groupItem.add("Franarea");
        groupItem.add("Motorul");
        groupItem.add("Rotile");
        groupItem.add("Siguranta si control");
        groupItem.add("Suspensia");
        groupItem.add("Transmisia");
    }

    ArrayList<String> groupItem = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Object> childItem = new ArrayList<Object>();

    public void setChildGroupData() {
        /**
         * Add Data For TecthNology
         */
        ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Java");
        child.add("Drupal");
        child.add(".Net Framework");
        child.add("PHP");
        childItem.add(child);

        /**
         * Add Data For Mobile
         */
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Android");
        child.add("Window Mobile");
        child.add("iPHone");
        child.add("Blackberry");
        childItem.add(child);
        /**
         * Add Data For Manufacture
         */
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("HTC");
        child.add("Apple");
        child.add("Samsung");
        child.add("Nokia");
        childItem.add(child);
        /**
         * Add Data For Extras
         */
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Contact Us");
        child.add("About Us");
        child.add("Location");
        child.add("Root Cause");
        childItem.add(child);
    }    
}
```

And the adapter class

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class NewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    public ArrayList<String> groupItem, tempChild;
    public ArrayList<Object> Childtem = new ArrayList<Object>();
    public LayoutInflater minflater;
    public Activity activity;

    public NewAdapter(ArrayList<String> grList, ArrayList<Object> childItem) {
        groupItem = grList;
        this.Childtem = childItem;
    }

    public void setInflater(LayoutInflater mInflater, Activity act) {
        this.minflater = mInflater;
        activity = act;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        tempChild = (ArrayList<String>) Childtem.get(groupPosition);
        TextView text = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.childrow, null);
        }
        text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text.setText(tempChild.get(childPosition));
        /*convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, tempChild.get(childPosition),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });*/
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return ((ArrayList<String>) Childtem.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groupItem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.grouprow, null);
        }
        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(groupItem.get(groupPosition));
        //((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find your `OnChildClickListener`, which you should implement.

This will give you access to the specific child clicked and hence the position in your `List` of items.

The implementation could look something like this example:

```
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    // Create a switch that switches on the specific child position.
    switch(childPosition) {
    case 0:
        // Go to child #0 specific class.
        Intent child0Intent = new Intent(this, Child0Activity.class);
        startActivity(child0Intent);
        break;
    case 1:
        // Go to child #1 specific class.
        Intent child1Intent = new Intent(this, Child1Activity.class);
        startActivity(child1Intent);
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

A full example of how to implement it can be found here:

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/10/android-expandablelistview-example.html

Comment: i've placed your code to the end of the Activity class, but i don't know if it's good because i need that every child to open a specific class.

Comment: that link doesn't helped me

Comment: ok, what i don't understand is where am i going to add all 3 classes that i want each different item to open when is clicked. in you example you only put MyChildActivity class to open, but for every child i want to open another class. That's my problem

Comment: it seems to be a logic code, but now when i added it the app stops. this code need to be placed in the main activity, right?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be placed in the `MainActivity`.